# (Mathematical statistics) Sum of independent poisson distribution

Tags: statistics, poisson-distribution

> Random variables X and Y each have a Poisson ($\lambda$) (i.e: X ~ Poisson ($\lambda$) and Y ~ Poisson($\lambda$).

The first part of the question asks to find the PMF of E(X+Y). I know that (X+Y) ~ Poisson ($\lambda + \lambda$) and my $P_x(k)$ will be:

$P_x(k) = \frac{e^{-\lambda-\lambda} \cdot (\lambda + \lambda)^{k}}{k!} $

The second part of the question asks to now assume that X=Y and to find the PMF of X+Y. Would this then imply that 2X~Poisson$(2\lambda)$? Would my PMF then be:

$P_x(k) = \frac{e^{-2\lambda} \cdot (2\lambda)^{k}}{k!} $

For some reason I feel like I'm doing something wrong. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $X = Y$, then $X + Y = 2X$.  What this means is that if you observe, for example, $X = 3$, then $X + Y = 2X = 6$.  And what this tells you is that $2X$ **cannot** be Poisson, because it is impossible for $2X$ to be an odd number.

What you can say, however, is that if $$\Pr[X = x] = e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^x}{x!}, \quad x = 0, 1, 2, \ldots,$$ then $$\Pr[2X = 2x] = \Pr[X = x] = e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^x}{x!}, \quad x = 0, 1, 2, \ldots.$$  So the random variable $2X$ has a "Poisson-like" distribution, but not over the nonnegative integers:  instead, its support is over the nonnegative **even** integers.  Another way to write this is $$\Pr[2X = m] = \begin{cases} \displaystyle e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^{m/2}}{(m/2)!}, & m = 0, 2, 4, \ldots, \\ 0, & \text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$$  This makes it explicit that $2X$ is not itself Poisson.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply!

This might sound like a stupid question but is the reason that 2X isn't Poisson because Poisson must support both odd and even nonnegative integers?

Comment: @TFSM  Yes.  Every Poisson distribution must admit a positive probability to any outcome that is a nonnegative integer.